# EditText text not overlapping over clear button in all 4 emulator devices I'm using, EXCEPT NEXUS 4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles, nexus-4

I have the following result in my `EditText`: *(from left to right)*

**Android Emulator:(Respectively)**
3.2QVGA API 15, Nexus S API 23
Nexus 5X API 23, Galaxy S7 API 24

[image]

Results in all 4 of devices are fine expect on my Nexus 4 where the result is the following:

**NEXUS 4 API 22:**

[image]

Here is my code:

**XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstNameTextInput"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstNameText"
                    style="@style/body_text_style"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_first_name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/black_clear_button_square_length"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/black_clear_button_square_length"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/firstNameClearButton"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/black_clear_button_square_length"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/black_clear_button_square_length"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear_black_svg" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="body_text_style" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/regular_black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/body_text_view_size</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
```

**dimens.xml:**

```
mdpi: <dimen name="body_text_view_size">13sp</dimen>
hdpi: <dimen name="body_text_view_size">13.5sp</dimen>
xhdpi: <dimen name="body_text_view_size">14sp</dimen>
xxhdpi: <dimen name="body_text_view_size">14.5sp</dimen>
xxxhdpi: <dimen name="body_text_view_size">15sp</dimen>

mdpi: <dimen name="black_clear_button_square_length">20dp</dimen>
hdpi: <dimen name="black_clear_button_square_length">21dp</dimen>
xhdpi: <dimen name="black_clear_button_square_length">22dp</dimen>
xxhdpi: <dimen name="black_clear_button_square_length">23dp</dimen>
xxxhdpi: <dimen name="black_clear_button_square_length">24dp</dimen>
```

**Tries:**
I even tried to hardcode a value of 100dp for end `padding` for my `firstNameText`

```
android:paddingEnd="100dp"
android:paddingRight="100dp"
```

All the devices (4 emulators) text was pushed even further to the left/start expect **Nexus 4**. It's almost like the device edittext is not reacting to these padding.

Comment: have you check by including ldpi as well ?

Comment: That's not the issue, like I mentioned, I hardcoded the value of paddingEnd/paddingRight, and all devices were affected by the change expect Nexus 4.

Comment: @RedM try below answer, It should solve your issue. By doing that even you don't need to care for upcoming future  devices/resolution. You don't need manage `body_text_view_size` and `black_clear_button_square_length` for each resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add drawableRight in your AutoCompleTextView, don't even need `ImageView`. Here is the modified layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstNameTextInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/firstNameText"
                style="@style/body_text_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_first_name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clear_black_svg" // added new
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/black_clear_button_square_length"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/black_clear_button_square_length"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Just tried it. It does work but it creates another problem. Now editText line does not go underneath (x) clear button anymore.

Comment: Oky then remove ImageView from the layout and add **android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clear_black_svg"** to your AutoCompleteTextView. See the updated answer

Comment: That's an option, but I'm using vectorDrawable and it does not work with drawableRight for API <21 only if done programatically. I'm trying to stick with XML for now, but if I'm not able to find a solution for this by EOD, I will make that change and programmatically pass my vectorDrawable for API<21. ;)

Comment: To not make it too complicated, as a workaround you can use [materialIcons](https://www.materialpalette.com/icons) as close icon is plain and simple.